# Finding right keras model - football prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, prediction

I was trying to generate a neural network (LSTM) able to predict the result of football games (win, lose, draw). In particular, I was trying to exted the algorithm in [this](https://github.com/krishnakartik1/LSTM-footballMatchWinner/blob/master/Set_Paper.pdf) paper to make it able to predict draws instead of only win or lose.
The training dataset has exactly the columns described at page 3. Those have all been scaled in order to be in a range from 0 to 1. Columns 9 and 10 are win/lose/draw encoded as 1 2 and 3, columns from 11 to 18 are binary values.
I modified the network created in the same github repository, resulting in this:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow import keras
import pandas as pd


# Build the RNN model
def build_model(allow_cudnn_kernel=True):
    input_dim = 27
    units = 64
    output_size = 3  # labels are from Win or Loss
    # CuDNN is only available at the layer level, and not at the cell level.
    # This means `LSTM(units)` will use the CuDNN kernel,
    # while RNN(LSTMCell(units)) will run on non-CuDNN kernel.
    if allow_cudnn_kernel:
        # The LSTM layer with default options uses CuDNN.
        lstm_layer = keras.layers.LSTM(units, input_shape=(input_dim, 1))
    else:
        # Wrapping a LSTMCell in a RNN layer will not use CuDNN.
        lstm_layer = keras.layers.RNN(
            keras.layers.LSTMCell(units), input_shape=(input_dim, 1)
        )
    model = keras.models.Sequential(
        [
            lstm_layer,
            keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
            keras.layers.Dense(output_size),
        ]
    )
    return model


def final_model():
    batch_size = 64
    data = pd.read_csv("onehotencoder/allAtt_onehot_large_train.csv")
    dataTrain, dataTest = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.2)
    row_count = dataTrain.shape[0]
    x_train, y_train = dataTrain.iloc[:, 2:29].values, dataTrain.iloc[:, 29:].values
    x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (row_count, 27, 1))
    row_count = dataTest.shape[0]
    x_test, y_test = dataTest.iloc[:, 2:29].values, dataTest.iloc[:, 29:].values
    x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (row_count, 27, 1))
    model = build_model(allow_cudnn_kernel=True)
    model.compile(
        loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
        optimizer="Adam",
        metrics=["categorical_accuracy"],
    )
    model.fit(
        x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), batch_size=batch_size, epochs=10
    )
    return model


model = final_model()
```

Than, I predicted some results:

```
data = pd.read_csv("onehotencoder/allAtt_onehot_large_train.csv")
dataTrain, dataTest = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.2)
x_test, y_test = dataTest.iloc[:, 2:29].values, dataTest.iloc[:, 29:].values
pred = model.predict(x_test)

j = 0
truth = []
correct_win = 0
correct_lose = 0
correct_draw = 0
for i in pred:
    if i[0] > i[1] and i[0] > i[2]:
        w = 1
    elif(i[1] > i[0] and i[1] > i[2]):
        w = 0
    else:
        w = 2 #draw
    if y_test[j][0] == 1:
        truth.append(1)
    elif y_test[j][1] == 1:
        truth.append(2)
    else:
        truth.append(0)
    if truth[j] == w:
        if w == 1:
            correct_win+=1
        elif w == -1:
            correct_lose+=1
        else:
            correct_draw+=1
    j+=1

print(str(correct_win)+"/"+str(truth.count(1)))
print(str(correct_lose)+"/"+str(truth.count(0)))
print(str(correct_draw)+"/"+str(truth.count(2)))
```

I kept the comments from the github repository, but do not really understand how this model works.
Three columns used as y_train are respectively for win, lose and draw, and should be one only if the event happens. I thought this was a good way to pass the input. The output was many arrays in a list, each one with a bunch of numbers which I assumed to be some kind of probability, so I took the highest as the outcome predicted.
I also do know that probably the way I calculated how the model is performing is not the best, and I am aware I should have used testing data not included at any point of the training. However, I think it should be performing better than this:

```
160/190 correct wins
0/131 correct lost
16/95 correct draws
```

There must be a logic error in the model creation, but I have no idea on how to fix this. I am not asking anyone to create this model for me, but I would love to understand what is wrong and if it is possible to fix this. I am aware that football predictions are very complicated to predict, but I guess it is possible to perform better than this.

Comment: 1. why lstm here? try a nn with only a few dense layers for this classification problem. 
2. what does your training metric say? what's happening with your loss? 
3. that for loop with if else if is a bit too funky :)

Comment: I know the loop is horrible, but i am very insexperienced with ml libraries and keras, if it is not obvious yet. I read online that that guy was not the only one using lstm, so I assumed it was a good choice. Thank you for your help @B.Kocis!

Comment: sure you can use lstm basically anywhere, that is more of the issue of the problem at hand. Nevertheless, it is always helpful to look into the training metrics.

Comment: Can you share with me the file `onehotencoder/allAtt_onehot_large_train.csv` and I can run it through and see what the output is on my end. Also, I notice you are spliting the data twice (once in the model, then again for the test/predict). You shouldn't do that (unless you set a seed so you get the same exact splits). Otherwise you might be leaking some of the data that the model was trained on into the test data set when you make those predictions.

Comment: And then yes, there is aflaw in your logic. You return the values for w as 1, 0, or 2. But then when counting up the correct ones, you're having it look for w as 1 or -1, (and then else).

Comment: I think you want to use `onehotencoder/allAtt_onehot_large_test.csv` for the prediction set. And you shoudn't need to split that, as the whole thing is your test set..

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems off here:

```
if truth[j] == w:
    if w == 1:
        correct_win+=1
    elif w == -1:
        correct_lose+=1
    else:
        correct_draw+=1
```

When in the previous line of code you are returning:

```
if i[0] > i[1] and i[0] > i[2]:
    w = 1
elif(i[1] > i[0] and i[1] > i[2]):
    w = 0
else:
    w = 2 #draw
```

So you will NEVER add on to `correct loss` as there is no value for `w = -1`...you only have it be `w` equal to `1, 0, or 2`. Provided the values are correctly assigned, I believe you should change one of the logics.

EITHER have:

```
for i in pred:
    if i[0] > i[1] and i[0] > i[2]:
        w = 1
    elif(i[1] > i[0] and i[1] > i[2]):
        w = -1  # <-- CHANGE from 0
    else:
        w = 2 #draw
    if y_test[j][0] == 1:
        truth.append(1)
    elif y_test[j][1] == 1:
        truth.append(2)
    else:
        truth.append(0)
    if truth[j] == w:
        if w == 1:
            correct_win+=1
        elif w == -1:     # <-- To match here
            correct_lose+=1
        else:
            correct_draw+=1
    j+=1
```

or

```
for i in pred:
    if i[0] > i[1] and i[0] > i[2]:
        w = 1
    elif(i[1] > i[0] and i[1] > i[2]):
        w = 0  # <-- to match here
    else:
        w = 2 #draw
    if y_test[j][0] == 1:
        truth.append(1)
    elif y_test[j][1] == 1:
        truth.append(2)
    else:
        truth.append(0)
    if truth[j] == w:
        if w == 1:
            correct_win+=1
        elif w == 0:  # <-- CHANGE to 0
            correct_lose+=1
        else:
            correct_draw+=1
    j+=1
```

But there's still something off as your sumbers are not summing up to 416 like it should.